# Health risk to my unborn child due to alcohol and drug use before finding out I was pregnant?

Tags: health, pregnancy, drugs, alcohol

We were not planning on getting pregnant so we both were not practicing healthy living habits! The only time  we were not careful having sex was only a few days (2days) after my last period which I knew was not in the fertile range. But that only time got me pregnant.

We are over the moon but so worried as I have been consuming alcohol pretty much 2 weekends last month (not excessive but some shots) and I smoked weed like every day but not excessive only a small amount like one of two puffs a day but that was mixed with tobacco. Also two weeks after my last period we partied and I had half an ecstasy too. Had I known I was pregnant I would have never touched any of those! I love kids, they are my favorite but I'm so upset without knowing I might have caused damage to my baby!

Please advise! I'm in to the 5th week now and from the moment I knew I was pregnant I stopped all and I started eating and drinking a lot of water, taking vitamins needed etc. But I am still worried of the substances I may have put in my body without knowing I was pregnant.

Comment: If you have an answer, please add it as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Of course the only way to be sure is to consult a health professional, but for some reason it seems consuming alcohol the first couple weeks doesn't harm the baby. Not knowing wifey was prego and then having a couple drinks has happened with two of our three babies and they are perfectly normal. Given she didn't get crazy drunk or anything, just a couple drinks. I have heard the same from many other people.

Time is the only way for you to know for sure, but for now I say relax, continue abstaining as you have been and wait until you can have an ultrasound to find out.

And Congrats!!!

Comment: I agree Jeff you don't need to worry about that. It is not dangerous in the first weeks of pregnancy. Congratulations !